# Can Silverlight HyperlinkButton forced to open page with Internet Explorer?

Tags: silverlight

Can Silverlight `HyperlinkButton` forced to open page with Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HyperLinkButton you can't. If your OOB app is in full trust mode you can use automation object [InternetExplorer.Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(VS.85).aspx) to open and control IE.

Comment: Thx, I've tried but SHDocVw component doesn't support Silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

If someone has defaulted to one browser (let say Chrome), you cannot ask the current browser (using JavaScript) to open the link to a specific browser (i.e. you want Internet Explorer instead of Chrome). I am not sure about Flash or Silverlight's ability to do what you want.

I have found a technique but it is specific to VBScript inside Excel and it may need the UA agent check to make sure it works correctly for a target environment if you want to adapt the similar code in Silverlight:

http://www.mofeel.net/87-microsoft-public-excel/30085.aspx

Comment: Almost there, but it seems it will access DOM (http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/Q_20781860.html) and in Silveright Out-of-Browser mode, DOM/scripting bridge is disabled. But thanks.

Answer (score -2):

If you have the right permissions in silverlight you can read and wright to disk. So yes you can.